Aerospike async client call closing and opening connections frequently
We have a flink application where we write data to aerospike. We are using aerospike async client call to write data to aerospike. The changes were working fine but one of the metrics were not ok for connections per user. As, the changes are now async, we see more increased fluctuations in client connection per user metrics.
Client code:
@Provides
  @Singleton
  public AerospikeClient aerospikeClient() {
    ClientPolicy policy = new ClientPolicy();
    EventPolicy eventPolicy = new EventPolicy();
    int eventLoopSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2;
    EventLoops eventLoops = new NioEventLoops(eventPolicy, eventLoopSize);
    policy.timeout = aerospikeConfig.getTimeout();
    policy.user = aerospikeConfig.getUser();
    policy.password = aerospikeConfig.getPassword();
    policy.eventLoops = eventLoops;
    return new AerospikeClient(policy, aerospikeConfig.getHost(), aerospikeConfig.getPort());
  }


What else can we add so as to stabilise connections?
Use figures to help set values if needed.
flink parallelism: x
flink worker nodes: y
aerospike nodes: z
Aerospike client: NA & EU
We thought of introducing AsyncMinConnectionPerNode but could still some fluctuations even after increasing it on local setup.

You can explore adjusting the parameters that prevent the socket from closing when idle. 1) on server side, ensure proto-fd-idle-ms is set to 0 - so server does not close idle sockets, uses "keep-alive" to detect clients that have gone away.  2) On client side, if you are using maxSocketIdle set to 0, tend thread will close idle sockets every 55 seconds till asyncMinConnsPerNode, then keep that many open. Hence, we recommend leaving maxSocketIdle at 0 with setting desired asyncMinConnsPerNode in ClientPolicy. 3) asyncMinConnsPerNode is is 0 by default - increasing that number so that each eventloop gets that number/number of eventloops - so budget for each eventloop accordingly - that may help.

Yeah, we tried increasing the asyncMinConnsPerNode but still the server side it was getting logged for every connection severals per second. Not sure why connections are getting created several per second.

Fluctuations are still fine, we are concerned with the frequent loggings happening at server side from our user, like serverals per second due to which their disk is getting spammed up.

Change server side logging level from info to critical? See for details: https://aerospike.com/docs/server/reference/configuration?ctx=logging&ver=7#logging__context and https://aerospike.com/docs/server/operations/configure/logging/aerospike-logs#dynamically-changing-the-severity-level

Also, initially connections are created at the rate of (20 / number of event loops) or (asyncMinConnsPerNode/number of event loops) - which ever is lower,  till they reach the minConnsPerNode number.

But server side is different team, not sure they'll be ready to do such changes. Currently, is there anything else we are missing from client side? Because for sync client it is logging for serveral per 20 min, but for async client is in per second.

BTW, I edited my response on maxSocketIdle - please re-read. When you said "server side logging" I thought you meant Aerospike server side logging.  On client side, you can play with increasing minConnsPerNode for sync client, asyncMinConnsPerNode for async.

Yes, I meant aerospike server side logging. On client side, we already retried increasing asyncMinConnsPerNode for async client but that didn't help.

Also, checked with aerospike server side proto-fd-idle-ms is set to 0

These are the logs which are frequently getting logged and filling disk memory:
2024-10-17 21:58:01 Oct 17 2024 16:28:01.034 GMT: INFO (audit): (security.c:7584) permitted | client: 192.168.65.1:59411 | authenticated user: myuser | action: authentication | detail: user=myuser
2024-10-17 21:58:01 Oct 17 2024 16:28:01.034 GMT: INFO (audit): (security.c:7584) permitted | client: 192.168.65.1:59409 | authenticated user: myuser | action: authentication | detail: user=myuser

Cross posted on Discord channel, answered there. This is different from minConns etc which is for sockets opened by an authenticated client.
